# Google Analytics: Connect acquisition data with server side reporting

Tags: java, spring, google-analytics, cross-domain, server-side

We have a system where user can arrive from multiple domains to an application system, and we would like to track their activity. The application system consists of several steps, and we would like to see, which utm_source brought in the most advancing candidates.

This can only be known on the backend, thus I'm using server-side event sending for GA.
I transfer to the backend:
_ga, _gid cookie values (from which we can extract the cid and gid parameters for the call. Is this a correct approach at all? I'm not 100% sure that cid and gid parameters should be filled from those values.

```
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("v", "1");
        body.add("tid", trackingId);

        // coming from the cookie _ga
        // ga id is like GA1.2.1051421203.1507107210
        // from that, we need: 1051421203.1507107210
        body.add("cid", cid);


        // coming from the cookie: _gid
        // _gid GA1.2.2063422210.1507532018
        // from that, we need: 2063422210.1507532018
        body.add("gid", gid);

        body.add("t", "event");
        body.add("ec", "Button");
        body.add("ea", "Click");
        body.add("el", label);

        addIfNotEmpty("cs", application.getUtmSource(), body::add);
        addIfNotEmpty("cm", application.getUtmMedium(), body::add);
        addIfNotEmpty("cn", application.getUtmCampaign(), body::add);

        log.debug("Sending event: {}", body);

        restTemplate.postForLocation(ANALYTICS_URL, body);
```

As far as we have the UTM source, fields filled, we can use it to link the data with our campaign in GA.

My question is:
How does Google Analytics link together the domain changes? I've read a bunch about cross domain linking, but did not find any good solution on what to do if the receiving site is a backend app.
I could use

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('linkerParam')
```

and transfer to the backend, and use it for event propagation, but that does not do the auto-linking. What any other params should be passed through to link the domain change?

Is there a way to make Analytics know about the user flow, without moving every time the utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign values? Shouldn't this be done by only sending the cid / gid correctly? If yes, where does this value should come from?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics doesn't care about linking domains. Your `postForLocation` will result in a new session in GA with your back-end server domain as a `hostname` field available in GA reports.
You'd probably only need `clienId` field in the Measurement Protocol POST request and Analytics help has a neat doc on that. Let say you have a visitor how came from source A, and then came again from source B and then later you backend sever sent an event of visitor's progress. Deciding what source to save and resent is tricky
The most reliable way to evaluate sources for this issue is switching to Multichannel reports in Google Analytics where you can look at First click conversions for source A and assisting conversions for source B and do not care about providing a source with your POST request.

Comment: I use the `ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');` to get the clientId, and I send this in the `cid` param. I see some `google / organic` hits in the analytics, so it may connect together the data from website A, with the data from website B's server side.
This shows me that it does not create a different session rather to connect with the previous one. Is it possible?

Comment: I'd suggest you use clientId as a custom dimension in your Google Analytics so you can later investigate each individual hits.
There definitely could be different GA source assignments for your POST based on many factors. here is some neat explanation of how GA source are assigned https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en and how the sessions are defined https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en Hope this helps